# How to add data from another collection to a retrieved Firestore onSnapshot collection (like foreign key relationship)?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs3

In my project I am using VueJS 3 (composition API) and Google's Firestore. I have two collections: company and country. One of the fields in a company document is a country ID (the country's ISO code). A country document has the ISO code as ID and a name property for the country name. I am using the following code to get my company collection:

```
const loadCompanies = async () => {
    await db.collection('company').orderBy(sortBy, sortDirection).onSnapshot(snapshot => {
            if (!snapshot.empty) {
                let records = snapshot.docs.map(company => {
                    // I tried to retrieve the country name here with, which finds it, but
                    // adds the country name too late:
                    let countryName = ''
                    db.collection('country').doc(company.data().country_id).get().then(country => countryName = country.data().name)

                    return { ...company.data(), id: company.id, country_name: countryName }
                })

                companies.value = records
            }
        },
        error => {
            ...
        })
}
```

With this I perfectly get an updated company collection, with every change in any of the company documents. I display the company documents in an HTML table. So far so good.
In my table however, I want to display the name of the country and not just the country ID (the ISO code), e.g. "Netherlands" instead of "NL".
How can I enrich my company collection with the additional country name value? I am able to find this name by executing a get() on the country collection within onSnapshot(), but because it's asynchronous, the company collection is returned before the country name is added.
P.S. The country ID in the company document can be empty!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just have to add async await? I never heard about all this stuff, but i think you just have to wait other responses.

```
const loadCompanies = async () => {
await db.collection('company').orderBy(sortBy, sortDirection).onSnapshot(async snapshot => {
        if (!snapshot.empty) {
            let records = await snapshot.docs.map(async company => {
                // I tried to retrieve the country name here with, which finds it, but
                // adds the country name too late:
                let countryName = ''
                await db.collection('country').doc(company.data().country_id).get().then(country => countryName = country.data().name)

                return { ...company.data(), id: company.id, country_name: countryName }
            })

            companies.value = records
        }
    },
    error => {
        ...
    })
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the code compile then returns an error, so that doesn't seem to be allowed. The error says "Unexpected reserved word 'await' "

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution: doing a forEach() after the companies have been retrieved via the asynchronous snapshot:

```
const loadCompanies = async () => {
await db.collection('company').orderBy(sortBy, sortDirection).onSnapshot(async snapshot => {
        if (!snapshot.empty) {
            let records = await snapshot.docs.map(async company => {
                return { ...company.data(), id: company.id, country_name: countryName }
            })

            companies.value = records

            // Now cycling through all company records and retrieve the country name from the country collection and adding it to the company array
            companies.value.forEach(company => {
                if (company.country_id !== '') {
                    db.collection('country').doc(company.country_id).get().then(country => 
                        company.country_name = country.data().name
                    )
                }
            })
        }
    },
    error => {
        ...
    })
}
```